# How to include git's commit id in the log's filename?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, logging, nlog, visual-studio-2022

`NLog` produces the following log filename `MyMachine_MyExe_1.0.0.0.log`. It includes the assembly version, but not the git's commit id which can be seen in dll's **Product version** property below.

Is there a way, either via `NLog.config` or programmatically to include the git's commit id in the log's filename?

**NLog.config**

```
<variable name="callsite" value="${callsite:includeNamespace=false:className=true:methodName=true}"/>
<variable name="baseLogDir" value="logs" />
<variable name="baseLogFilename" value="${machinename}_${processname}_${assembly-version}" />
<variable name="debugTraceLayout" value="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${callsite}|${message}" />
<targets>
    <target
        xsi:type="Console"
        name="console"
        layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message}" />
    <target xsi:type="File"
        name="fileInfo"
        fileName="${baseLogDir}/${baseLogFilename}.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message}"
        archiveFileName="${baseLogDir}/archive/${baseLogFilename}_{#}.log"
        archiveNumbering="Date"
        archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"
        archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd_HHmmss" />
```

**MyProject.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <Target Name="SetSourceRevisionId" BeforeTargets="InitializeSourceControlInformation">
        <Exec Command="git describe --long --always --dirty --exclude=* --abbrev=8" ConsoleToMSBuild="True" IgnoreExitCode="False">
            <Output PropertyName="SourceRevisionId" TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" />
        </Exec>
    </Target>       
</Project>
```

**MyLibrary.dll Properties**

[image]

Comment: The easy way is to compile an attribute into your assembly `<ItemGroup><AssemblyMetadata Include="SourceRevisionId" Value="$(SourceRevisionId)" /></ItemGroup>`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, can you explain how to use that information to get what I want?

Comment: You can refer to the [MSBUILD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022) documentation, it can do a lot of related things, and can help you with the problems you may encounter later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define additional assembly attributes in your msbuild project;

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <Target Name="SetSourceRevisionId" BeforeTargets="InitializeSourceControlInformation">
        <Exec ...></Exec>
        <ItemGroup>
            <AssemblyMetadata Include="SourceRevisionId" Value="$(SourceRevisionId)" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>       
</Project>
```

Which I believe you can use to define NLog's [Global Diagnostic Context](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer) (GDC)

```cs
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set(
    "SourceRevisionId",
    typeof(Program).Assembly
        .GetCustomAttributes<AssemblyMetadataAttribute>()
        .Where(a => a.Key == "SourceRevisionId")
        .Single()
        .Value
);
```

And define the output filename;

```
fileName="${baseLogDir}/${gdc:item=SourceRevisionId}.log"
```